# Анти-Анти Отладка

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Необходимо отладить процесс, на котором стоит "защита" от отладки.

Умелые разработали библиотеку ScyllaHide. Вот опенсурс: https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide
Она позволяет выполнить необходимое мне задание - отладить то, что защищено от отладки.

Вопрос в том, как использовать эту библиотеку для Visual Studio?
В документации этой библиотеки, указано, что она не привязана к конкретным дебагерам, но как использовать для остальных( в моем случае VS), не указано.
Может быть ее вообще нужно инжектить в саму программу, которую я хочу отладить и только потом отлаживать Visual Studio.

Дополнительно сообщаю, что я буду отлаживать не сам процесс, а лишь свою библиотеку (свой проект на VS), которую подгружает эта программа в процессе работы.

Comment: Разобраться каким образом оно обнаруживает дебагер, и поправить все как было :) там минимум 7 способов проверки, от тривиальных, до регистров контента. А вообще ломать чужой софт **не хорошо** :)

Comment: @NewView, я уже со всем этим ознакомился. Я не хочу изменять ту программу к которой подключаюсь, а отлаживать свою dll, которую приложение вызывает. Поэтому и возникают такие сложности. Мне нужно знать, как visual studio настроить, может быть есть какой плагин/дополнение, чтобы можно было отладить программу, которая ловит дебагеры.